Do all International airports need to be certified by ICAO?
Amidst the recent accident of Jeju Air Flight 2216 in South Korea, and many experts mentioning that there was a bad construction design of the embankment holding the ILS array, I think I've heard long time ago (if I'm not wrong) that international airports have to be certified by ICAO or something like that, so I wonder if it was the case at Muan Airport.
So, beyond any factors involved for this particular accident, simply my only question is if ICAO needs to certify the construction of all International Airports (or the company that builds the airport) in any way shape or form.

ICAO does not directly certify the construction or operation of international airports.
Instead they provide Standards and Recommended Practices (SARPs) through Annex 14 of the Chicago Convention, which covers "Aerodromes."
These standards set out the requirements for the design, construction, and operation of international airports.
But it's up to the country's aviation authority to make sure if their airports are following these standards
In this document, it has been written

1.2.5  RECOMMENDATION
Those portions of the strip immediately beyond the limits of the runway should be so prepared or constructed as to minimize hazards, arising from differences in load bearing capacity, to an aircraft running off the runway.

In addition, 1.2.4 regulates the longitudinal and transverse slopes of strips beyond the runway to ensure safe conditions for aircraft that might veer off the runway.
So there are standards set by ICAO, ideally they should be followed, they aren't always followed though.


Do all International airports need to be certified by ICAO?


They have to be certified
They are certified by local authorities.

All international airports in an ICAO State member have to be locally certified, according to all applicable ICAO standards.

ICAO and Civil Aviation Convention
ICAO:

Is a UN agency which role is to facilitate international civil flights, by creating agreed standards and recommendations.

Is made of aviation agency representatives from all State members, as well as representatives of other organizations like meteorology (WMO) and radiocommunications (ITU) international agencies.

Is  not a certification agency. It's much more comparable to a standardization organization like ISO.


ICAO State members have signed a Convention and its Annexes which contain both standards and recommendations. State members have to implement all standards, unless impossible to do so (Annex 2, Rules of the Air).
Recommendations are only suggestions for State members. In ICAO Annexes, recommendations are explicitly identified by "recommendation" and are in italic type.
ICAO Convention and its Annexes are treaties committing States, not citizens. Standards and recommendations must be implemented in local regulations to become applicable to citizens in a country.
The mandatory way to inform the international aviation community about local aviation regulations in use is to publish them in the aeronautical information publication (AIP).
Each State member publishes its own AIP.
General case
Aerodrome certification is described in Annex 14 and details are given in Doc 9774:

1.4.1 States shall certify aerodromes used for international operations in accordance with the specifications contained in this Annex as well as other relevant ICAO specifications through an appropriate regulatory framework.


1.4.2 Recommendation.— States should certify aerodromes open to public use in accordance with these specifications as well as other relevant ICAO specifications through an appropriate regulatory framework

Note the difference: 1.4.1 is a standard, international airport must be certified. 1.4.2 is a recommendation, other airports open to public use should be certified.
Korea case
In Korea AIP, at section AD 1.1:

1.2 Applicable ICAO documents: ICAO Standards and Recommended Practices contained in the ANNEX 14 are applied to the maximum extent possible.
ANNEX 14 - Aerodromes Volume I & II
Doc 9157 - Aerodrome Design Manual(Part 1 to 6)
Doc 9137 - Airport Services Manual(Part 1 to 9)

As usual in all AIP, the GEN 1.7 section is used to indicate if the local law ignores or modifies some ICAO standard, with an explanation of the difference. This is to comply with by Article 38 of the Convention.
This section is sorted by ICAO Annex number. Certification of aerodromes is part of Annex 14 (aerodromes):

1.0.1 The Republic of Korea defines "Aerodrome Certificate" in ICAO Annex 14 as "Airport Operating Certificate". Airport Operating Certificate means a certificate, issued by Ministry of Land, Infrastructure and Transport.


1.4.2 The Republic of Korea certifies airports used for international operations mandatorily and the certification will be expanded to other airports open to public use.

Airports certification statuses are listed at section AD 1.5 (Muam was certified in Nov. 2007).

References:

ICAO Convention and annexes
Annex 14, Volume I, Aerodrome Design and Operations (pdf)
Doc 9774, Manual on Certification of Aerodromes (pdf)
Doc 10066, Aeronautical Information Management (pdf)

